# Input does not reflect ngModel value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to do some custom validation based on a json object a user gives me. 
However the input field visually does not show the value of the ngModel property. I added a plunkr to illustrate the problem.

'use strict';

```
angular.module('zendantennesApp')
    .directive('validation', function ($compile, $parse) {
        return {
            scope: {
                validation: '@',
                ngModel: '@'
            },
            require: "?ngModel",
            restrict: 'A',
            compile: function(el, attrs) {
                el.removeAttr('validation');
                el.attr('ng-blur', 'evaluateExpression()');
                el.attr('ng-focus', 'assignOriginalValue()');
                var fn = $compile(el);
                return function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
                    ngModel.$render = function(){
                    $(element).val(ngModel.$viewValue);
                    };
                    fn(scope);
                }
            },
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.originalValue = $scope.ngModel;
                $scope.validationObject = JSON.parse($scope.validation.replace(/'/g, '"'));
                $scope.evaluateExpression = function(){
                    console.log($scope.validationObject);
                };
                $scope.assignOriginalValue = function(){
                    $scope.originalValue = $scope.ngModel;
                    console.log($scope.originalValue);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/1qYxCiSZWHgVeN9CEpxw?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**validation** directive will have isolated scope and hence parent scope value will not be accessible unless you explicitly mention during compile. Replace `fn(scope);` by `fn(scope.$parent);`

[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lVBdT6BNK4UxtpBS7KbZ?p=preview)